# Evaluate the integral using the residue theorem

Tags: complex-analysis

$$\int_C \frac{e^{πz}} {{z^{2}}{(z^{2}+2z+2)}}dz,$$ where C is the circle of centre 0 and radius 3, traversed in the anticlockwise direction.

I can see there are singularities at $z=0$, $z=-1+i$ and $z=-1-i.$

I have found the residues at $z=-1+i$ and $z=-1-i$ which are both $ \frac{-e^{-π}} {{4}}$.

I am struggling to find the residue at $z=0$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The pole at $z=0$ is of second order.  The corresponding residue at $z=0$ can be found using [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Residue_(complex_analysis)#Limit_formula_for_higher_order_poles) as the limit

$$\text{Res}\left(\frac{e^{\pi z}}{z^2(z^2+2z+2))}\right)=\lim_{z\to 0}\frac{d}{dz}\left(\frac{e^{\pi z}}{z^2+2z+2}\right)$$

Can you finish now?